# Definition of Dual Lattice

Tags: lattice-crypto, terminology, dual-lattice

1- Can someone explain why we have the definition of dual of a lattice like
$\Lambda^*=\{\vec{v}\in span(\textbf{B}): \langle \vec{v},\vec{x} \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall \vec{x} \in \Lambda\} $.

2- There is an explanation in the lecture note of Daniele Micciancio, (CSE206A) Spring 2007, [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp07/cse206a/lec8.pdf), but I cannot follow some parts of it.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the highlighted lines, we first note that for any invertible matrix $M$ for the field of definition of the inner product we trivially have
$$\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = \langle \mathbf x,M\cdot M^{-1}\mathbf y\rangle.$$
Using this with the matrix $M=\mathbf B^T\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf y=f(\mathbf x)$ we see that
$$\langle x,f(\mathbf B)\rangle=\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf B^T\mathbf B(\mathbf B^T\mathbf B)^{-1}f(\mathbf B)\rangle.$$

We now note another property of the inner product that
$$\langle M\mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle=(M\mathbf x)^T\mathbf y=\mathbf x^TM^T\mathbf y=\langle \mathbf x,M^T\mathbf  y\rangle.$$
It follows then that
$$\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf B^T\mathbf B(\mathbf B^T\mathbf B)^{-1}f(\mathbf B)\rangle=\langle \mathbf B\cdot\mathbf x,\mathbf B(\mathbf B^T\mathbf B)^{-1}f(\mathbf B)\rangle.$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Daniel S, for noting a property of inner product: *looking an inner product as product of a row vector and a column vector*.

**I just write it for clarity in the case someone is not familiar with basic mathematical concepts.**

We look at vectors as column vectors (so $\vec{v}^{T}$ is a row vector). $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m\geq n$, is the basis of the lattice.

> ... since every linear function $f:\mathcal{L}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $f_{\vec{v}}(\vec{y})=\langle\vec{v},\vec{y}\rangle$

For $\vec{y}_{m\times1}\in\mathcal{L(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n})}$, we can write it based on the basis of the lattice: $\exists\vec{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}$: $\vec{y}=\mathbf{B}\vec{x}$.

$$f(\vec{y})=f(\mathbf{B}\vec{x})=f(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\vec{b}_{i})$$

Because when multiplying a column vector to basis matrix from *right*, it's equivalent to linear combinations of column vectors of the basis matrix. All the time, the first (second, ...) element of $\vec{b}_{1}$ ($\vec{b}_{2},\ldots$) multiplied by first (second, ...) element of $\vec{x}$.

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}f(\vec{b}_{i})$$

because $f$ is linear.

$$=\langle\vec{x},[f(\vec{b}_{1},\ldots,f(\vec{b}_{n}))]^{T}\rangle$$

by looking at this serie as an inner product of two vectors. Note $f:\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, so $f(\vec{b}_{i})\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $[f(\vec{b}_{1}),\ldots,f(\vec{b}_{n}))]\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ is a vector.

$$=\vec{x}^{T}_{n\times1}\cdot\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n})}_{n\times1}$$

by looking at inner product as product of a row vector and a column vector.

$$=\vec{x}^{T}_{n\times1}\mathbf{B}^{T}_{m\times n}\cdot(?)\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B})}_{n\times1}$$

trying to construct $\mathbf{B}\vec{x}$, the argument of $f$ at the first line.

$$=\vec{x}^{T}_{n\times1}\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}\cdot(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B})}_{n\times1}$$

$\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m\geq n$ is a rectangular matrix; it doesn't have inverse. $\mathbf{B}$'s columns are basis vectors of the lattice, so are linearly independent. $\Rightarrow$ $(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})_{n\times n}$ has inverse (Note: $(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^{T})_{m\times m}$ is not invertible).

$$=(\mathbf{B}\vec{x})^{T}_{m\times1}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}_{n\times n}\cdot\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B})}_{n\times 1}\right)}_{\vec{v}}$$

$\vec{v}=\left(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}_{n\times n}\cdot\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B})}_{n\times 1}\right)$ is in the linear span of the lattice. Because $f:\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, so $\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n})}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ $\Rightarrow\vec{v}'=(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}_{n\times n}\cdot\overrightarrow{f(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n})}_{n\times1}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ $\Rightarrow\vec{v}=\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}\cdot(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}f(\mathbf{B})=\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}\cdot\vec{v}'_{n\times1}\in span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbf{B}_{m\times n})=\{\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}\vec{w}:\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\}$.

$$=\langle\vec{y},\vec{v}\rangle$$

again by looking inner product as product of a row vector and a column vecror.

---

**Finally**, we've reached to the equality $f(\vec{y})=\langle\vec{y},\vec{v}\rangle$ for all $\forall\vec{y}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})$ and some vector $\vec{v}\in span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))=span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbf{B})$ (because $\mathbf{B}$ is the basis of the lattice $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})$, so $span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))=span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbf{B})$).

In other words, we can write a linear function $f:\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ as $f(\vec{y})=f_{\vec{v}}(\vec{y})=\langle\vec{v},\vec{y}\rangle$ for some $\vec{v}\in span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbf{B})$, i.e., *represent it with a vector*.

Now we substitute this representation in the natural definition of duality for lattices:

$$\left(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})\right)^{*}=\{f:\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})\rightarrow\mathbb{Z} \ | \ f \ \text{is linear}\}=\{\vec{v}\in span_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbf{B}): \langle\vec{v},\vec{y}\rangle\in\mathbb{Z},\forall\vec{y}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})\}$$

---

As it was noted in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_lattice), It should be emphasized that a lattice and its dual are fundamentally different kinds of objects; one consists of vectors in Euclidean space, and the other consists of a set of linear functionals on that space.